# How to show that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(x))$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider $f(x)=7x^3-25x^2-5 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. I want to show that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(x))$ is a field. How do I do this? I want to use the fact that $R/I$ is a field if $I$ is maximal, but I don't know how to continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Bbb Q$ is a field, $\Bbb Q[x]$ is a Euclidean domain. In particular, $\Bbb Q[x]$ is a PID. Thus, every prime ideal in $\Bbb Q[x]$ is maximal.

Is $(f(x))$ prime? Hint: Show that it's irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that $f$ is irreducible. Use Eisenstein's criterion and Gauss' Lemma.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you have to prove that $f$ is irreducible.

Since $f$ has degree 3, it suffices to prove that $f$ does not have as factor of degree 1, which you may assume monic. So, just prove that $f$ has no rational root. The [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) may be useful for that.